# Error publishing multiple density split APKs to Play Store

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**Background**

I'm building 10 APKs for my app using two flavors and 5 density splits:

```
productFlavors {
    flavorA {
        ...
    }
    flavorB {
        ...
    }
}

// Builds APKs for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, and universal
splits {
    density {
        enable true
        exclude "ldpi", "xxxhdpi"
    }
}
```

Each APK gets a unique versionCode. Each APK only contains one drawable folder that matches the desired target density.

After creating a new release in the Play Store developer console all APKs are successfully uploaded. When moving forward with reviewing the release the following error message is displayed:

> Fully shadowed APK PROBLEM
>
> This APK will not be served to any users
> because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher
> version codes. RESOLUTION Remove this APK from your release or review
> the targeting and version codes of the APKs that you are including in
> this release.

Running aapt on the APKs shows that the all have the same target screens and densities:

> supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
>
> supports-any-density: 'true'
>
> densities: '160' '240' '320' '360' '65534'

Worth mentioning is that none of the above are explicitly set in the manifest file.

**The Question(s)**

I was expecting each density split APK to automatically get a [Google Play filter](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SupportedFilters) added, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Is this something I need to do manually, and if so how? I can't find anything in the documentation that explains how it's supposed to work. Or am I simply missing something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that you have to include `compatibleScreens` for the correct filter to be added to the manifest file. Updating the build script to look like this solves the problem:

```
splits {
    density {
        enable true

        // Optional: Exclude any screen densities your app doesn't support
        exclude "ldpi", "xxxhdpi"

        // Add all screen sizes your app supports (mine is a wearable app)
        compatibleScreens 'small'
    }
}
```

Running aapt on the new APKs results in the same output as before, but Play Store no longer complains about shadowing. You will also see something like

```
Screen layouts: small@hdpi
```

under APK details in the Google Play Console.

Answer (score 0):

```
splits {
    density {
        enable true
        exclude "ldpi", "xxxhdpi" //IMPORTANT: only if you want to exclude some density
        compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge' // IMPORTANT: all supported by your application
    }
}
```